# how to parse html text using R?

Tags: html, r

I have a sample html codes for the table

```
<td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td>
<td>Hope, Bob</td>
<td>7</td>
<td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">7</td>
<td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">7</td>
<td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td>

<td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td>
<td>Tan, Sally </td>
<td>76</td>
<td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">76</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">23</td>
<td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">53</td>

<td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td>
<td>Smith, Mark</td><td>2</td>
<td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td>
<td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">2</td>
<td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td>
<td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">2</td>
```

I would like to parse the text within `<td></td>` and turn it into a table. Each observation begins with name and followed by 11 columns of information (numbers) like this

```
X1          X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 
Hope, Bob    7  0  0 0%  0 0%  0 0%  7   7   0 
Tan, Sally  76  0  0 0%  0 0%  0 0% 76  23  53
Smith, Mark  2  0  0 0%  0 0%  0 0%  2   0   2
```

I have tried using `html_table` but it couldn't read text.
I have tried datapasta to copy and paste from the website but it didn't work.
I have tried using these codes too, but couldn't really get to do the above output

```
test <- read_delim("eval num.txt", delim = "\n", col_names = FALSE)
test$X1 <- str_match(test$X1, "<td>[a-zA-Z0-9%,. ]+</td>")
```

Please englighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first block of code isn't a valid HTML table, so you're going to have trouble.  It needs to be wrapped in `<table> ... </table>`, and each row needs to be wrapped in `<tr>...</tr>`.  I don't see either of those tags in your sample.

I can put them in by hand, assuming each row of your sample is a row in the table.  This gives the HTML code

```
<table> 
<tr><td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Hope, Bob</td><td>7</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">7</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">7</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Tan, Sally </td><td>76</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">76</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">23</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">53</td></tr>
                       <tr> <td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Smith, Mark</td><td>2</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">2</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">2</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Then if you put that text in a string, the `rvest` package can convert it to a dataframe.  For example,

```
sample <- '<table><tr><td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Hope, Bob</td><td>7</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">7</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">7</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Tan, Sally </td><td>76</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">76</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">23</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">53</td></tr>
                       <tr> <td class="rgGroupCol">&nbsp;</td><td>Smith, Mark</td><td>2</td><td style="background-color:#BCD4E8;">0</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#D2DEE8;"><span class="details_gridpercentage">0</span>0%</td><td style="background-color:#ECE1BA;">2</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">0</td><td style="background-color:#F3ECCC;">2</td></tr> </table>'

library(rvest)
sample1 <- minimal_html(sample)
sample1 %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

This prints the table

```
  X1          X2 X3 X4  X5  X6  X7 X8 X9 X10
1 NA   Hope, Bob  7  0 00% 00% 00%  7  7   0
2 NA  Tan, Sally 76  0 00% 00% 00% 76 23  53
3 NA Smith, Mark  2  0 00% 00% 00%  2  0   2
```

It's only finding 8 columns of data, and that's all I see in the HTML; I don't know why you think there should be 11.

**Edited to add:**

Based on the comment, you don't want to parse the HTML, you want to remove all the HTML tags.  This code does that:

```
notags <- gsub("[<][^<>]*[>]", " ", sample)
```

This uses regular expressions: `[<]` represents the single character `"<"`.  You can probably use just  `<` without the square brackets, but I always forget which characters have special meaning in regexps, so that might not work.

Then `[^<>]` represents any character except `"<"` or `">"`, and the `*` says "zero or more" of these.  Finally, we have the closing `>` in brackets.

So `gsub` replaces anything that looks like an HTML tag with a single blank.  I don't know all the rules of HTML to know if there are cases where 
it would do the wrong thing, but it should handle most cases.

Once you get rid of the tags, you can read the new string using read.table:

```
read.table(text = notags)
```

and using the same `sample` as above, you'll get this result:

```
      V1     V2    V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
1 &nbsp;  Hope,   Bob  7  0  0 0%  0 0%   0  0%   7   7   0
2 &nbsp;   Tan, Sally 76  0  0 0%  0 0%   0  0%  76  23  53
3 &nbsp; Smith,  Mark  2  0  0 0%  0 0%   0  0%   2   0   2
```

This seems to be pretty close to what you want; I'll leave the last bit of cleanup to you.

Comment: Thanks. X5, X6, X7 data are supposed to 0 0%, instead of together. I was wondering if there is a way to parse/extract information between > and <

Comment: Wow! That's great! Thank you! Can you explain the meaning of [<][^<>]*[>] please? thanks

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much! Very helpful